# Null Reference error

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to store an image into isolated storage by using a button event handler.however when I click the "save" button, theres a null reference error which it could not get the image to store into isolated storage.Someone help me please.Urgent

Below are my sample code :

```
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {
        String tempJPEG = "TempJPEG";

        var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
        {
            myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);


        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("TestImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None; 
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);


        Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        myFileStream.Close();
```

Comment: Where's the error being thrown? If it's on the uri line, try using `"/TestImage.jpg"`

Comment: Strange how incomplete info do you provide. What about the callstack for the exception thrown? Does the program break on the exception thrown? (VS menu > Debug > Exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always like to add error handling to check and see if I got the object I expected to get. You can either recover from the situation or wrap your exception in a more descriptive exception. This will yield long term benefits in your code and identify your near term problem. That would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see anything obviously wrong. Where exactly does it fall over? My advice would be to stick a breakpoint in and step through line by line and inspect any elements you think might be causing the problem.